# Error parsing triggers Cannot find module when deploying firebase function

Tags: firebase

I am implementing a firebase function endpoint that requires I authenticate with two different projects. Information found on SO and other sources suggest this

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'; 
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccountSource = require('./source.json');
const serviceAccountTarget = require('./target.json');

const sourceAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountSource)
})
const targetAdmin =  admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountTarget)
s}, "destination")
```

Where source.json and target.json are files storing the serviceAccount credentials (JSON) obtained from the Project Settings => Generate New Private Key.

My folder structure is as follows

```
functions/
   index.ts
   source.json
   target.json
```

Running the following

```
npm run-script lint
```

produces no errors, however when I run

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './source.json'
```

Firebase admin / functions versions as follows

```
"firebase-admin": "7.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.2.0"
```

Typescript

```
"typescript": "^3.2.2"
```

Any ideas as what is causing the error.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Typescript try moving your source.json to the lib folder.

Comment: This is accurate as the lib folder contains the index.js where it will look for the file from that path, otherwise specify full path

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this. Although documentation on the firebase admin functions (parameters etc) seems to be very scarce I did notice that the credential.cert member takes a ServiceAccountPathOrObject.
I tried

```
const sourceAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('./source.json')
})
```

This failed with a path not found but this time it gave the path. From this I was able to see that there was a missing element in the Path

```
const sourceAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('./src/source.json')
})
```

The function deployed. I then tried to go back to the original code and added the 'src' folder to the path - however that resulted in the same error.

I prefer the above solution but I am still interested to know what caused the original error - given that much of the documentation out there seems to recommend this including this https://gist.github.com/brunobraga95/82bef0672ce451767107e62df1d8b28f - which is the code I am trying to implement.

The function has deployed and is working - so I can confirm the recommendation above works.